# How to save an associating record between has-many classes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, has-many, has-many-through, belongs-to

I've created three classes to represent *Books*, *People*, and *BookLoans*. While I am able to show the association of People to Books through BookLoans I've been seeding my database.

I now need to save a checkout of a book. It was my intention to do this action through the book controller. Specifically, creating a loan action in the BooksController. While this makes sense to me in theory I am having a terrible time implementing the appropriate syntax.

I've added the ability to loan a book from the show view of a book. This view now contains a form which uses the loan action of the book controller to record the loan.

I've added what I believe are the appropriate methods to my Book model. With the help of [theIV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124674/theiv) I have captured the appropriate information in the Controller. Unfortunately, when I press Loan on the book show view a book_loan record is no being recorded.

What am I missing?

**Book Model**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_loans
  has_many :borrowers, :through => :book_loans, :source => :person

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_loans, :allow_destroy => true

  def loaned?
    book_loans.exists?(:return_date => nil)
  end

  def current_borrower
    if loaned?
      book_loans.first(:order => "out_date desc").person
    end
  end

  def add_loan (person_id)
      book_loans.create(:book_id => id,
                        :person_id => person_id,
                        :out_date => Date.current)
  end
end
```

**Loan Method from BooksController**

```
def loan
  @book.add_loan(params[:book_loan][:person_id])

  redirect_to :action => 'book', :id => params[:id]
end
```

**Book Show View w/ Loan Form**

```
<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%=h @book.title %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Isbn10:</b>
  <%=h @book.isbn10 %>
</p>
<p>
  Currently loaned to:
  <%=h borrower_name(@book) %>
</p>

<% form_for(@book) do |x| %>
  <p>
    <%= x.label :loan_person_id %><br/>
    <%= collection_select(:book_loan, :person_id,
      Person.find(:all, :order => 'name ASC'), :id, :name) %>
    <%= x.submit 'Loan', :action => 'loan' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**BookLoan Model**

```
class BookLoan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :person
end
```

**Person Model**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_loans
  has_many :books, :through => :book_loans
end
```

**Development Log**

```
Processing BooksController#update (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-09-24 13:43:05) [PUT]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Loan", "authenticity_token"=>"XskHLuco7Q7aoEnDfVIiYwVrMEh5uwidvJZdrMbYYWs=", "id"=>"1", "book_loan"=>{"person_id"=>"3"}}
  [4;35;1mBook Columns (3.0ms)[0m   [0mSHOW FIELDS FROM `books`[0m
  [4;36;1mBook Load (4.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT * FROM `books` WHERE (`books`.`id` = 1) [0m
  [4;35;1mSQL (0.0ms)[0m   [0mBEGIN[0m
  [4;36;1mBook Load (1.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT `books`.id FROM `books` WHERE (`books`.`title` = BINARY 'Dreaming in Code: Two Dozen Programmers, Three Years, 4,732 Bugs, and One Quest for Transcendent Software' AND `books`.id <> 1) LIMIT 1[0m
  [4;35;1mSQL (1.0ms)[0m   [0mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/books/1
Completed in 19ms (DB: 10) | 302 Found [http://localhost/books/1]
  [4;36;1mSQL (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSET NAMES 'utf8'[0m
  [4;35;1mSQL (0.0ms)[0m   [0mSET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0[0m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `has_many` a model, you get access to a few extra methods, two in particular are `collection.build` and `collection.create`— `build` is like `new`, `create` is like `create` :). Have a look at the [has many documentation](http://www.railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M004174). In this case, you could rewrite add_loan as

```
def add_loan (person_id)
  book_loans.create(:book_id   => id,
                    :person_id => person_id,
                    :out_date  => Date.current)
end
```

or something similar.

To answer your question about what the view will be sending to the controller, it will send the `params` hash as usual, but if you just want to pass the `person_id` to `add_loan`, you can extract that. Assuming that the part of the view you have above is wrapped in a form for a book loan, you can access the person by `params[:book_loan][:person_id]`. You'll also want to do a find in that action first, or else `@book` is going to be nil.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

EDIT: I'm not sure if the way you have it right now works, but I think you want to change your `Person` model to read

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_loans
  has_many :books, :through => :book_loans
end
```

EDIT 2: Your development log says you aren't actually hitting `loan`, you're hitting `update`. A few things you could do: check to make sure you have `loan` as a listed resource in your routes; merge the `loan` action into the `update` action—could start getting kind of messy so I don't know if this is the best approach. I'm sure there are more, but those are the first things that pop to mind. Also, I don't know if you can add `:action => 'loan'` to a submit tag. I think it will just look at that as if it were an html option. You might want to change your `form_for` to read

```
<% form_for(@book), :url => { :action => 'loan' } do |x| %>
```

once you've made sure that the routes are in order. But as I said earlier, I'm pretty sure you will be thrown an error on that action because you haven't defined a `Book.find` for it.

Comment: What would be the best option for creating a view. For simplicity sake I'd like to use the book as a jumping off point and that's why I was thinking of just passing the person_id. For the time being I was going to attempt adding an additional form to the book edit.

Additionally, thanks for the catch on Person I would have spun my wheels for a bit.

Comment: You could add a `fields_for` for the book loan to your book form. You could also look into `accepts_nested_attributes_for` http://www.railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.4/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Sorry, to expand a bit on the previous comment. If you add a `fields_for` for your book loan, you should build a book loan in your controller first—`@loan = @book.book_loans.build`— and then do the fields_for on @loan

Comment: modified my question to incorporate your suggestions but am still having an issue getting the record saved.

Comment: What does your development log say?

Comment: Added development log to question.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I have a much firmer understanding of a lot of RoR concepts now.